# Change the font of PDField

Tags: pdfbox

I am working with an acroform which has fields. These fields specify their own fonts to use when a value is set (using `setValue`).

Is there a way to override this font of the PDField, such that `setValue` text appears in a different font.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not perfect, but it worked for me

```
if (field instanceof PDTextbox)
{
    field.getDictionary().setString(COSName.DA, "/Cour 10 Tf 0 g");
    field = new PDTextbox(acroForm, field.getDictionary());
}
field.setValue(value);
```

Unfortunetelly, you have to use inconvenient notation and create a new object for the change to take effect. I will improve this answer if I find an easier solution.